# Question on Structured Adaptive Mesh Refinement (SAMR) grid boundaries

Tags: computational-physics

From my review of the literature, it looks like the SAMR methods of Berger et al. have become one of the industry standards in AMR work.  This being the case, the question I have must have been answered many times, but I can't find an answer anywhere.  Maybe it's just obvious to everyone except me?  Anyway, here it is:  Let's say we have a 2D computational grid that needs refinement, and the cells that needs refinement are arranged like so:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxAAA
  BBBxxx
  xxxxxx
  xxxxxx
```

The "A" and "B" cells are not special compared to the others.  I label them specially because they are about to cause a problem for me.  Now, I want to cluster these cells efficiently and so I apply some algorithm, maybe the Berger-Rigoutsos algorithm that gets alot of play.  And it perhaps divides the cells up into two rectangles like so:

```
 -------
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
| xxAAA |
 -------
   --------
  | BBBxxx |
  | xxxxxx |
  | xxxxxx |
   --------
```

Now, if I take these clusters at "face value", the lower row of the upper grid and the upper row of the lower grid will now be treated as external boundaries of these two grids.  The overlying points in the coarse mesh will not receive data from calculations on these refined meshes.  The exact opposite will occur and the coarse data will actually be supplied to these external points (not *really* external) from the coarse grid.  This includes both the "A" and "B" points.

However, it is clear from the original layout of cells needing refinement that "A" and "B" points *must be internal points*.  They must be calculated on the refined grids as internal points.

So what do I do?  I can think of a couple of ways to fix this that involve "adjusting" the cluster boundaries a bit.  However, as I mentioned, SAMR and the Berger-Rigoutsos method of clustering have received alot of usage over the years, so I am thinking there must be some established way of handling this.  I thought I would check and see if anyone knows what that might be before I re-invent the wheel.  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of ghost cells? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @KyleKanos  Well, that is what I am thinking.  But no one ever mentions it.  So I thought I would check things out before, like I said, I re-invent the wheel.